# Getting error : "VCEnd" exited with code -2147023082"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I am compiling a c++ com code. This application will run as service.
Visual Studio 2010 is used for compilation and its launched with admin privileges.
When I compile I am getting the below error

"Error MSB3073: The command "D:\PTService\PT_Service......\Bin_Release\PT_Service.exe" /Service echo regsvr32 exec. time > "......\Bin_Release\regsvr32.trg" echo Server registration done!
:VCEnd" exited with code -2147023082.   C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets"

I believe due to this error my service is not starting

Comment: Debug the service registration.

Comment: An out-of-process COM server exe is never registered with Regsvr32.exe since it does not export a DllRegisterServer entrypoint.  So Project > Properties > Linker > General > Register Output needs to be No.  It tends to be done by running the exe file with the /regserver command line option, depends on what code you wrote.